# JS function returns undefined (Scope, local, global var?)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been looking into scopes, global var and local var and tried my best to make it work without success. I hope someone can solve this for meg and maybe I'll finally get how it works.

I have a function to return the status of a IP camera.

```
console.log(info.IsRecording);
```

Does print the correct boolean value that I want the function to return. But camInfo holds nothing. So then obviously return camInfo returns undefined.

Function:

```
function camStatus(camId){
    var camInfo;
    var request2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request2.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8124/Json/GetCamStatus?sourceId=' + camId + '&authToken=xxx', true);
    request2.send(null)
    // state changes
    request2.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request2.readyState === 4) { // done
            if (request2.status === 200) { // complete   
                var info = JSON.parse(request2.responseText);
                camInfo = info.IsRecording;
                console.log(info.IsRecording);
            }
        }
    }
    return camInfo;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look again

Comment: Think about it like this: camInfo is set inside the onreadystatechange callback, but that callback isn't run immediately. If it doesn't run before the `return` happens, what will be returned?

Comment: What does camInfo equal if you change the line to camInfo = (info.IsRecording == true);

Comment: But the console.log is inside the callback, so it should be fine.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Okay. So I'm trying to return something that hasn't happened yet. Correct? Thanks!

Comment: @RuneAspvik Basically. This type of problem pops up constantly when writing JS though, so make sure you have a firm understanding of what's going on here and how to avoid it. The dupe link is a great resource.